# document.execCommand wont work with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom

I am currently working on an editable part of my HTML. I am using document.execCommand method, but however I can't get it to work with addEventListener. But, with inline javascript it work. This is the code that don't work.

```
let btn = document.getElementById('click');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
 document.execCommand("bold")
 let a = document.execCommand("bold") ? true: false;
 console.log(a);
})
```

But, If I use inline, it work

```
<button id="click" onclick="document.execCommand("bold")">CLICK</button>
```

Does the document.execCommand method behave differently when invoked inside addEventListener?

Comment: What are you bolding? what do you think `document.execCommand("bold")` returns?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I shouldn't use that ternary operator. The ternary operator just overwrite the method. It work if I don't use the ternary operator.  Now I change my question. How to get the state when document.execCommand is on or off?

Comment: You fire up the command second time, i think thats the problem.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss, Yes, indeed, that is the problem. I forget that I fired the function second time there. What I want to achieve initially is how to get the state of document.execCommand, how to get the state when it's on or off.

Comment: The boolean returned does not tell you if it applied it or not, it tells you if it was able to apply the command.

Comment: @epascarello yes, I am a little confused here with the ternary operator. How to know if a method is applied or not?

Comment: It is just telling you if it ran. It has nothing to do with the bold state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is the fact you are expecting the Boolean to be if the bold was added or removed. Problem is [the Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) just tells you if what was selected was able to toggle bold. It has nothing to do if it was added or removed.

So what can you do to detect it? Well you can look at what is in the current selection and see if a parent element is bold. Or you can use a method `queryCommandState` which seems to be [poorly documented everywhere](https://w3c.github.io/editing/execCommand.html#querycommandstate()) which allows you to see what the state of the current selection is. Combine it with selection change event and you can determine if it is applied or not.

Basic Idea:

```js
var btnBold = document.querySelector("button")
btnBold.addEventListener("mousedown", function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var x = document.execCommand("bold");
  console.log(document.queryCommandState('bold'));
})

document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function (evt) {
  btnBold.classList.toggle("active", document.queryCommandState('bold'));
})
```

```css
div { outline: 1px solid black; }
button.active { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<div id="x" contenteditable="true">
 Foo Bar
</div>
<button>Bold</button>
```

Comment: Great ! I can get it to work now, thank you very much, sir !